# Unable to mount a network drive

Tags: mount, networking

I am trying to mount a Windows drive onto my RPI but it is asking for a password.

First:

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.xx.xx.xx/Users/Username/Folder1/Folder /mnt/folder cifs sec=ntlm,defaults,rw,username=username,password=password 0 0
```

After this it asks for a password:

```
Password:
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I tried the drive's password and the RPI password but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use the line from /etc/fstab as the arguments to mount.cifs.

On the command line you put the need something like this:

`sudo mount.cifs -o sec=ntlm,defaults,rw,username=username,password=password //192.xx.xx.xx/Users/Username/Folder1/Folder /mnt/folder`

If you put your what you have in the /etc/fstab like this:

`//192.xx.xx.xx/Users/Username/Folder1/Folder /mnt/folder cifs sec=ntlm,defaults,rw,username=username,password=password 0 0`

You should be able to mount it with the command:

`sudo mount /mnt/folder`

It will look up the information for mounting /mnt/folder from /etc/fstab to perform the mount.